# Estudiando métodos constantes

Tags: c++, poo

Buenas a todos,

estoy estudiando los métodos constantes en C++, pero tengo un ejemplo el cual lo expongo a continuación

Sea la **clase Persona**

```
    class Persona
    {
    public:
    //....    
    string& nombre();
    const string& nombre() const;
    private:
    string nombre_;
    };
```

Y las **definición** de dichas **funciones** públicas:

```
inline string& Persona::nombre() { return nombre_; }
inline const string& Persona::nombre() const {return nombre_; }
```

Y el **programa principal**:

```
int main()
{
Persona p1;
p1.nombre() = "ProgrammerJR"
const Persona p2 = p1;
}
```

Mis dudas son las siguientes:

1) Tenemos un objeto no constante (p1) y otro que sí lo es p2. Por eso intuyo que el ejemplo mostraría que al sobrecargarse la función, un objeto llamaría a su función no const y el objeto constante mediante sobrecarga llama a las funciones const. ¿Estaría bien eso?

2)En la definición de funciones que os expongo, se divide en la versión const para el objeto const y la otra es para el objeto no const.
Entonces en la definición del método const:

```
inline const string& Persona::nombre() const {return nombre_; }
```

En el const después de inline, digamos que devuelvo un dato que es de un objeto constante, pero entonces en la clase no debería de tener un dato nombre_ que fuera constante?
Es decir:

```
class Persona
{
//...
private:
const string nombre_;
};
```

Gracias a todos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Tenemos un objeto no constante (`p1`) y otro que sí lo es `p2`. Por eso intuyo que el ejemplo mostraría que al sobrecargarse la función, un objeto llamaría a su función no `const` y el objeto constante mediante sobrecarga llama a las funciones `const`. ¿Estaría bien eso?

Tu intuición es correcta, pero ¿por qué fiarse de la intuición pudiendo comprobarlo?

```
struct S
{
    void f()       { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
    void f() const { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
};

int main()
{
    S p1;
    const S p2;

    p1.f(); // muestra void S::f()
    p2.f(); // muestra void S::f() const

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vmcA2DClfl3UilWj)</kbd>.

> Devuelvo un dato que es de un objeto constante, pero entonces en la clase ¿no debería de tener un dato `nombre_` que fuera constante?

No. La palabra clave `const` es un cualificador; es decir: **cualifica** un objeto. Un objeto cualificado como constante lo es en su totalidad, tanto el objeto como sus sub-objetos.

Esta cualificación se extiende hacia abajo (si el objeto superior es constante, lo serán todos los sub-objetos) pero no hacia arriba (si un sub-objeto es constante, no hará que sea constante el objeto superior).

La cualificación puede poner pero no se puede quitar<sup>1</sup>, imagina:

```
struct S{};

void f(const S &s)
{
    // Aqui 's' es constante.
}

void g(S &n)
{
    // Aqui 'n' no es constante.
}

void main()
{
    S s;        // Aqui 's' NO es constante
    const S n;  // Aqui 'n' es constante

    f(s);       // 's' sera constante dentro de 'f'.
    f(n);       // 'n' sera constante dentro y fuera de 'f'.
    g(s);       // 's' no es constante ni dentro ni fuera de 'g'.
    g(n);       // Error, no se puede quitar la constante a 'n' dentro de 'g'.

    return 0;
}
```

Sabiendo esto podemos comprobar que lo dicho de los sub-objetos es cierto:

```
struct S
{
    std::string normal;
    const std::string constante;
};

void f(std::string &normal) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
void f(const std::string &constante) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }

int main()
{
    S p1;
    const s p2;

    f(p1.normal);    // muestra void f(string&)
    f(p1.constante); // muestra void f(const string&)
    f(p2.normal);    // muestra void f(const string&)
    f(p2.constante); // muestra void f(const string&)

    return 0;
}
```

También puedes verlo en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YrE6kclExnNadVQx)</kbd>.

**Otras cosas a tener en cuenta**.

**No** devuelvas referencias no constantes a datos internos de tus objetos, eso rompe el principio de [encapsulamiento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulamiento_(inform%C3%A1tica)).

---

<sup>1</sup>A no ser que se use una conversión de tipos que elimine la cualificación, cosa que no suele ser aconsejable.

Answer (score 4):

> Tenemos un objeto no constante (p1) y otro que sí lo es p2. Por eso intuyo que el ejemplo mostraría que al sobrecargarse la función, un objeto llamaría a su función no const y el objeto constante mediante sobrecarga llama a las funciones const. ¿Estaría bien eso?

Correcto, esa es la idea: `p1` llama a las versiones *normales*, y `p2` (si llamaras a algún método, que no llamas a ninguno) llamaría a las versiones `const`.

> En el const después de inline, digamos que devuelvo un dato que es de un objeto constante, pero entonces en la clase no debería de tener un dato nombre_ que fuera constante?

**No**. La única forma de que llames a esa función seria sobre un objeto constante ... en el cual, **todos las variables-miembro serian ya constantes**.

Cuando haces `const int x`, estás diciendo, desde ya, que ese objeto **ES** constante. Pues si lo aplicas a clases

```
struct Algo {
  int b;
};

const Algo a;
```

es lo mismo: estás diciendo que `a` **ES** constante ... lo cual **es exactamente lo mismo** que si haces

```
struct Algo {
  const int b;
};
```

Osea: aplicada a una instancia de clase, `const` **convierte automágicamente todas las variables-miembro en `const`**. Lo cual es mas versátil que hacerlo nosotros en la definición de la clase (y tendríamos que hacer 2 clases distintas, una *normal* y otra `const`).

Piensa en `const` como si el compilador colocara el objeto en memoria de solo-lectura; si no puedes escribir, da igual la variable-miembro que pretendas cambiar: no podrás hacerlo en ninguna. En la práctica, es como si usaras `const` en todas.

Answer (score 0):

Sentencias como esta:
`const Persona p2 = p1;` no son recomendables. 
La instrucción obliga a ejecutarse al constructor de copia de p2, que no está definido con lo que utilizará el constructor de copia por defecto que como todo lo "por defecto" no es seguro y está fuera del control del programador. Cuanto menos es inseguro.
Para inicializar objetos, lo correcto es usar el constructor explícito. Para objetos simples como estos, puede funcionar lo que haces pero con objetos algo más complejos no.

Además, si declaramos un objeto constante, el compilador tiene que asegurarse que no van a cambiar sus atributos durante el tiempo de vida del objeto. Un objeto const sólo puede llamar métodos const y, serán el compilador y el enlazador los que se aseguren de que el método no cambie atributos.

Saludos.